# cannot find sql table from entity framework scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I just created an asp.net mvc 3 application and added these classes and then added the controller to supply the CRUD pages. When going to those pages i can do everything that's expected but for some reason i cannot find where the data is being stored.

I checked the App_Data (with Show All Files enabled) but there is no db there
I searched my db 'DbTest1' but i could'nt find any table with the created agent names.

Any thoughts?

Model class:

```
public class Agent {
        public int AgentId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Agent Name")]
        public string AgentName { get; set; }
    }
```

DbContext:

```
public class AgentContext : DbContext {
        public AgentContext() : base("ApplicationServices") { }
        public DbSet<Agent> Agents { get; set; }
    }
```

connection String:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=SMITH\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DbTest1;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: nope. CRUD operations all work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your connection string name to DbContext name,

```
<add name="AgentContext" connectionString="Data Source=SMITH\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DbTest1;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: The Connection String is already explicitly set in the base constructor of the the context. Changing it will mean EF will be looking for the a non-existent connection string in Web.Config

Comment: Yeah, i've done that already for sanity purposes. This is very odd that i cannot find where the data is being stored. I know it's somewhere, somewhere very obvious.

Comment: can you use SQL server management studio to connect to your `SMITH\SQLEXPRESS` instance?

Comment: yes, i can connect to my instance. Oddly enough i just created another mvc application and recreated the steps to get to this problem, and everything worked just fine. There's something wrong with this proj and i need to examine this a little deeper. i'm assuming something is amiss in the web.config for project that's having issues.